# D3DCompile E_INVALIDARG

Tags: c++, direct3d

I had some problem with D3DCompile here. I'm writing a UWP application that has CX\C++ Runtime.
There is a code

```
    const std::string shaderSource =
        "struct PixelShaderInput\n"
        "{\n"
        "    float3 color : COLOR0;\n"
        "};\n\n"
        "float4 main(PixelShaderInput input) : SV_TARGET\n"
        "{\n"
        "    return float4(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);\n"
        "}";


    HRESULT hr = D3DCompile(
        shaderSource.c_str(), 
        shaderSource.length(),
        NULL, 
        NULL, 
        NULL, 
        "main", 
        "ps_5_0", 
        NULL,
        NULL, 
        &pShaderCode, 
        &errorBlob);
```

As a result, I get E_INVALIDARG.

Interestingly, if I make a mistake in the text of the shader (for example, do not write another entry point), then the result is a specific compilation error.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you misspelled "main" as "min" in your shader code?

Comment: oh yeah, I checked that the error in the shader would not return the E_INVALIDARG. ))

Comment: The next thing you do when you get a failure is to look at `errorBlob`.  Did you do this?

Comment: Yeap. And all what a see is a "invalid argument"

Comment: I am try add UINT compileFlags = D3DCOMPILE_DEBUG | D3DCOMPILE_SKIP_VALIDATION | D3DCOMPILE_SKIP_OPTIMIZATION; But nothing

Comment: Make sure you aren't using the legacy DirectX SDK at all with your UWP project which could end up pulling in the wrong (outdated) version of ``D3DCompile``. Also, you should use ``nullptr`` instead of legacy ``NULL``, which means in the last two cases of ``NULL`` you should be using ``0`` instead--they are flags not pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The legacy DirectX SDK should not be used for UWP app development.

See [MSDN: Where is the DirectX SDK?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) and [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/03/22/where-is-the-directx-sdk/).

The Windows SDK for Windows 8.0, Windows 8.1, and Windows 10 already includes all the latest DirectX headers including the latest version of D3DCompile (version #47 as opposed to the legacy DirectX SDK's version #43). See [HLSL, FXC, and D3DCompile](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/05/07/hlsl-fxc-and-d3dcompile/)

A few bits of the legacy DirectX SDK are deprecated and not available in the Windows SDK, in particular D3DX9, D3DX10, and D3DX11. See [Living without D3DX](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/08/20/living-without-d3dx/).

> Really, you shouldn't need the legacy DirectX SDK even for Win32 desktop development except when you are still targeting Windows XP -or- if you need XAudio2 on Windows 7. See [The Zombie DirectX SDK](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/03/23/the-zombie-directx-sdk/).

Answer (score 0):

yeap, drop old SDK and it works!